# Cannot get models to display attributes

Tags: javascript, marionette

I would like to know why this is not displaying the entries I created.  I am struggling to find good simple tutorials that use Marionette so I took the angry cats tutorial found here (http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/) and tried to make something similar but even simpler so I could understand what is going on better.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Javascript, I am using Marionette.js

```
    MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addRegions({
    listBox : "#listBox"
    });

    Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        entry : "Blank"
    },
    });

    EntryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Entry
    });

    EntryView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "entry-template",
    tagName: 'tr',
    className: 'entry'
    });

    EntriesView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: "table",
    template: "#entries-template",
    itemView: EntryView,

    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
        collectionView.$("tbody").append(itemView.el);      
    }
    });

    MyApp.addInitializer(function(options){
        var entriesView = new EntriesView({
            collection: options.ents
        });

        MyApp.listBox.show(entriesView);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ents = new EntryList([
            new Entry({ entry: 'abc' }),
            new Entry({ entry: 'def' }),
      new Entry({ entry: 'ghi' })
  ]);
   MyApp.start({entry: ents});
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Simple Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/screen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "listBox">
        </div>

        <script type="text/template" id="entries-template">
            <thead>
                <tr class='header'>
                    <th>Entry</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </script>
      <script type="text/template" id="entry-template">
            <td><%- entry %></td>
            <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
      </script>
        <script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
        <script src="js/demo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're not using the right key in your options. You should have:

```
var entriesView = new EntriesView({
    collection: options.entry
});
```

As a side note, my "angry cats" tutorial is a bit dated. To learn the basics about using Marionette views, you'll be better off reading this free pdf: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf (it's the free sample to my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction))

In addition your template selector isn't valid: you need to have "#entry-template" where you have "entry-template".

Comment: When I made the change you suggested I got this error - Uncaught NoTemplateError: Could not find template: 'entry-template'.  Does your change mean i should also change the template as well?  And thanks for the link to the book, I searched for a Marionette book and got nothing.

Comment: I've updated my answer: your template selector is missing "#"